# Offline first via browser storage or device storage?

Tags: webview, pouchdb

I previously worked on an app that used Couchbase-lite for mobile storage. this app was a native Android app. But I think it would be possible to replicate most of what that app did with a web-view via pouchdb or something similar.

I'm assuming that a webview would act the same as a browser in terms of cookies/data persistence/etc, or at least allow access to webpage that would cache information on the device.

Would there be any drawbacks for creating an offline-first mobile app via browser features instead of using a mobile devices storage? i.e. What would the cons be of creating a webview-based app that used PouchDB, instead of a cordova or native app that used Couchbase-lite?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure whether there is difference between a webview-based app and cordova app. Cordova basically wraps your app in a native webview. So maybe you want to specify what you mean with a webview-based app in a little more detail.

Comment: i think that since the couchbase-lite mobile sdks are available to both cordova and native apps, that a cordova app in this case is interacting with the device storage. I'm not sure if it's possible to use browser storage in cordova? if so, then that is what I'm really asking. For a cordova app would it be better to use the browser storage or device storage for an offline approach?

Comment: but having quickly googled 'pouchdb cordova', it looks like it wraps around sqlite - so device storage? so actually a webview would be different in that you would actually be using the browser storage (if this is possible... which I'm not sure is)

Comment: Check out the docs on [PouchDB adapters](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html)... Pouch might use browser storage (WebSQL on iOS, IndexedDB on Android) or device storage (via SQLite plugin)

Comment: so in that case can I say that for a browser satisfies requirements (no background tasks, no advanced native functionality, etc) that a browser - based solution to 'offline-first' is just as reasonable as a using device storage?

Comment: though I guess you would have to take into account expected storage footprint..?

Comment: Yep quota on mobile browsers might be a problem if you're expecting a larger storage footprint... https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/ might be a good starting point, if it is still up to date...